# Item could not be retrieved: Internal Server Error

Tags: heroku

the activity of github z heroku doesn't work for[enter image description here][1] me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZfIh.png

Comment: Seeing the same behavior

Comment: Please remember to search for existing questions before asking a new on, as described in [ask]. This has been an ongoing issue for over a month and the canonical question is quite easy to find.